# How to implement a TypeConverter for a type and property I don't own?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, typeconverter

This is annoying:

```
<GeometryDrawing>
    <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
        <Pen Brush="Black"/>
    </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
</GeometryDrawing>
```

I want this:

```
<GeometryDrawing Pen="Black"/>
```

So I write a `TypeConverter`:

```
public class PenConverter : TypeConverter
{
    static readonly BrushConverter brushConverter = new BrushConverter();

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string)) return true;
        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        var s = value as string;
        if (a != null)
        {
            var brush = brushConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString(s) as Brush;
            return new Pen(brush, 1);
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

Now, how do I link it up with the `Pen` type? I can't just add a `TypeConverterAttribute` to it as I don't own it (nor do I own `GeometryDrawing.Pen` property).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/849202/284795

Answer (score 2):

[This link here](http://www.kinlan.co.uk/2006/10/assigining-typeconverter-to-class-you.html) claims you can do something like (copied verbatim, credits to that guy)

```
public static void Register<T, TC>() where TC: TypeConverter
{
 Attribute[] attr = new Attribute[1];
 TypeConverterAttribute vConv = new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(TC));
      attr[0] = vConv;
 TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(T), attr);
}
```

The last part of that method seems to do the trick.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I call AddAttributes before InitializeComponent and it still throws. :(

Comment: Did you check if the Typeconverter works at all after adding it by accessing TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Pen))?

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Benjamin Podszun does not work here  because the XAML parser appears to ignore attributes added via the `TypeDescriptor`, bindings however do not, so you could use one to work around this:

```
<GeometryDrawing Pen="{Binding Source=Black}"/>
```

Not very elegant i concede, similarily you could use a [markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855815.aspx) as a pen factory...