# C# How to resolve circular dependency caused by EditorAttribute usage?

Tags: c#, circular-dependency

In my project I have two libraries that would currently result in a circular dependency which I am unable to resolve.

One library provides common data structures for the whole solution. This library contains a construct similar to this:

```
namespace Common {
  public class Foo {
    //[Editor( typeof( UserEditor ), typeof( UITypeEditor ) )]
    public UInt32 OwnerId { get; set; }
  }

  public class User {
    public UInt32 Id { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Now in one of the projects in our solution, we would like to edit `Foo` instances through a PropertyGrid and the `OwnerId` property should be edited with a custom editor; this one:

```
using Common;

namespace Common.Gui {
  public class OwnerEditor : UITypeEditor {
    public static List<User> Users { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Now, I can't just add an `EditorAttribute` to `Foo.OwnerId` because that would create a circular dependency and I would like to keep references to `Common.Gui` out of `Common` anyway. I would also like to avoid pulling code out of `Common` into a new assembly as a lot of other projects reference it.

I found a question regarding [adding `EditorAttribute` at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043579/adding-editor-editorattribute-at-run-time-dynamically-to-an-objects-property), which sounded like a perfect solution, but I was unable to adept that to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is a sign of a flawed design. Do you want the class library containing `Foo` to be unknowning of the editing GUI? In that case it shouldn't contain the EditorAttribute.

One solution could be to regard the `Foo` class as your model in a MVVM architecture. Then you can create a wrapping ViewModel in the GUI class library where the `EditorAttribute` is applied. If you extract an interface IFoo which i placed in your model class library you can  use the decorator pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You can reference the editor class by name to create a runtime reference.

```
public class Foo {
    [Editor( "Common.Gui.OwnerEditor, Common", typeof( UITypeEditor ) )]
    public UInt32 OwnerId { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: However, I do agree with Anders' answer. Your Common module still knows about your GUI module, so it's not a great design.

Comment: +1: You can see this all over the MS libraries referring to the *.Design.dll 's.

Comment: In fact, I tried that to resolve the dependency initially, but it caused the editor to not be used in the PropertyGrid. Edit: My mistake, that was caused by a typo. This suggestion works fine now.