# How to specify a custom UITypeEditor for all instances of a generic closed-source type?

Tags: c#, .net, typedescriptor, uitypeeditor

How can I specify a custom UI editor for all instances of a *generic* type? The type is defined in another assembly, which I don't own.

---

This is what I tried, inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/849778/284795 but it didn't have any effect (the old editor remains). Here, the generic type is `List<>` and the custom editor `DateTimeeditor` - nonsense but this is just an example OK.

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(List<>),new EditorAttribute(typeof(System.ComponentModel.Design.DateTimeEditor),typeof(UITypeEditor)));
TypeDescriptor.GetEditor(new List<int>(),typeof(UITypeEditor)).Dump();
```

Comment: Just derive your own class from that type so you can give it your own [Editor] attribute.

Comment: Don't think it's possible this way. TypeDescriptor resolution mechanism is based on a dictionary of types, and there is no event you could hook on.

Answer (score 0):

Try something in the lines of

`Customer` is an arbitrary class

`EditorBase` is defined as

```
public class EditorBase : System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor {
}
```

Code:

```
System.Collections.Hashtable table = new System.Collections.Hashtable();

table.Add(typeof(Customer), typeof(EditorBase).AssemblyQualifiedName);

System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.AddEditorTable(typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor), table);

object editor = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetEditor(typeof(Customer), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor));
```